# Obfuscate sensitive data in Wagtail Markdown or custom editor fields

Tags: markdown, obfuscation, wagtail

I would like to know best approach in obfuscating sensitive data in Markdown (wagtail-markdown) or any other custom fields. The use case is to prevent bot scrapping for email and phone number on legally required Impressum pages in Germany.

So far I have tried I one of the email encoders online and pasting the output in Markdown but that's just parsed as text in the end. Also I have seen Wagtail documentation mentioning to [register a rewrite handler](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/v4.1.1/extending/rich_text_internals.html#registering-rewrite-handlers), but that is tied to RichTextField types. How can I do that same workflow work with any text field? What is the best approach overall?

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your email address to unicode then use it with javascript:location to create the link (presuming you want a link, but similar process for other uses).

1. Use the ord function with lambda to convert each character in the
   mail address string, padding each character code to length 4 with
   re.sub.
2. Create the mailto/tel href's and add as a template variable.

Code:

```
import re    
email = "somebody@somewhere.com"
uni = (re.sub('.', lambda x: r'\u%04X' % ord(x.group()), email))
mailto = (f"javascript:location=&#39;mailto:{uni}&#39;;void0")
print(mailto)
```

Output:

```
javascript:location='mailto:\u0073\u006F\u006D\u0065\u0062\u006F\u0064\u0079\u0040\u0073\u006F\u006D\u0065\u0077\u0068\u0065\u0072\u0065\u002E\u0063\u006F\u006D';void0
```

Template:

```
<a href="{{ mailto }}">Contact</a>
```

Rendered:

```
<a href="javascript:location='mailto:\u0073\u006F\u006D\u0065\u0062\u006F\u0064\u0079\u0040\u0073\u006F\u006D\u0065\u0077\u0068\u0065\u0072\u0065\u002E\u0063\u006F\u006D';void0">Contact</a>
```

The unicode is rendered back to ascii in the client mail app

[image]

If you want to actually display the email/phone, there's not much to do about that that I could think of other than using PIL to generate on-the-fly png's with the info embedded.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

Template tag/filter

```
from django import template
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

register = template.Library()

def obfuscate_string(value):
    return ''.join(['&#{0:s};'.format(str(ord(char))) for char in value])

@register.filter
@stringfilter
def obfuscate(value):
    return mark_safe(obfuscate_string(value))

@register.filter
@stringfilter
def obfuscate_mailto(value, text=False):
    mail = obfuscate_string(value)
    if text:
        link_text = text
        # Detect subject lines
        if ';' in text:
            args = text.split(';')
            link_text = args[0]
            subject = args[1]
            mail = mail + '?subject=' + subject
    else:
        link_text = mail
    return mark_safe('<a href="{0:s}{1:s}">{2:s}</a>'.format(
        obfuscate_string('mailto:'), mail, link_text))
```

Template

```
{% load i18n email_obfuscator %}


{{ some_email|obfuscate_mailto }}
```